# How to open an iframe from clicking an image

Tags: html, iframe

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I'm hoping I can open an iFrame in the centre of my webpage from clicking a picture. So in effect the iframe would be hidden until the picture is clicked. I have a very small and simple upload form on another page that I would like to appear when the user needs to upload and click the picture. I've had a good look round on this site and google in general but not found what I'm looking for, or the basics weren't included because it's common knowledge for most people here. Would there also be a way of closing this when it's finished uploading too? The form currently diverts to the homepage when finished so It would be handy to have a close option as in the end (post successful upload) the iframe contents will be the same as the page it's displayed on.

The best/easiest I have come across has been on w3schools but I have read using html for iFrames is not widely accepted or it isn't the best option cross-browser.

I have been viewing and trying different code but without even the basic knowledge I can't get my head around it.

If anyone is able to help, please assume I'm 5 years old. I'm not daft but in terms of code I'm literally just starting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a javascript onclick function to your img tag which would open a new window upon a click.  You would pass the window.open function the name of the html file you want to display.  Something like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="window.open('welcome.html')">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me. That's great for opening in another window. I'm on the Basekit platform, so they include 'open in new window' an easy option. I was hoping to open the upload form within an iframe on my home page. Hidden at first then revealed when the picture is clicked. Would that be possible?

Comment: I've never used Basekit so I'm not really sure.  But this is standard HTML/Javascript so if you're able to type in code it should work.  You should edit your post to include Basekit as a tag and mention that you're using Basekit in your description.

Comment: I understand what you mean. By mentioning Basekit, I just meant that opening in a new window is easily done automatically. I was just hoping I could, for example, be on my home page...have a button that reads upload (Which I have).. then when the user clicks upload, an I frame appears with the content from one of my other pages. Basekit isn't the issue. I can embed html, javascript and jquery as you would with a normal site, probably easier, I'm just looking for the code that makes the Iframe with content from another page appear upon clicking a picture. Thanks for you help.